# Como fechar um ServerSocketChannel?

Tags: java, socket

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
Selector socketSelector = SelectorProvider.provider().openSelector();
ServerSocketChannel serverChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
serverChannel.configureBlocking(false);
serverChannel.register(socketSelector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
serverChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(1331));

new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
           Thread.sleep(5000);
           serverChannel.close();

        } catch (InterruptedException | IOException ex) {
        }
    }
}.start();
```

Obs: O código não esta completo, é apenas um teste.

Esse código deveria abrir a conexão com a porta 1331, e depois de 5 segundos rodando deveria fechar a conexão, liberando a porta para uso. Porém, caso eu use essa linha:

```
serverChannel.register(socketSelector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
```

A porta não é liberada, somente se eu a remover, mas se eu remover não posso aceitar clientes.

Como posso dar um jeito de liberar a porta sem ter que fechar a aplicação ?

Answer (score 0):

Fiz um teste utilizando a parte de código que postou e verifiquei que a conexão está fechando corretamente. Ao tentar escutar uma porta enquanto seu serviço está rodando, obtenho a seguinte exceção: `java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind`, mas após os cinco segundos, o serviço funciona corretamente.

Servidor:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1331);
Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
```

Cliente:

```
Socket kkSocket = new Socket("localhost", 1331);
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(kkSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(kkSocket.getInputStream()));
```